# NotSuppportedException IL2CPP on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, mono, il2cpp

When I try to send data to my service I get the exception below on Xcode Debug.log when using iOS 11 and an iPhone 5s. On my login and register scenes I'm using WCF service to check login data. I cannot reach the service because of this exception. When I tried to make Mono instead of LL2CPP I get exceptions on Unity Console.

[Xcode Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrPZn.png)

[Unity Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FJdo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the code you are using won't work with iOS with either Mono or IL2CPP. Based on the Xcode Exception you attached, the library you are using is calling `System.Reflection.Emit` to generate code at runtime. This is not allowed on iOS.

IS there a version of the WCF service that works with AOT platforms? If so, I would try that.